# Link Multiple Files on Wandbox

Tags: wandbox.org

http://melpon.org/wandbox provides a cloud based C++ compiler, which allows me a lot of flexibility; most notably the ability to compile more than one file.

I can create a permlink to code using the rather unintuitive ["Link" > "Wandbox Simple"](http://melpon.org/wandbox/nojs)

After I select a compiler thought that lands me at a page with *only 1* textbox for entering source code. I can add say "x.cpp" and "y.cpp" to the compiler options, but I can't find a way to enter those files code as part of the permalink.

I know it is possible to have more than one file in a permlink. I found this for example while searching for how to do this: http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/3CADzrEX9RH7NZQt

Can anyone tell me how to place multiple files in a Wandbox permlink?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To link multiple files, or really the easy way to link *any* Wandbox code, is as follows:

1. Write all files
2. Click "Run"
3. After running a "Share This Code" button will appear, click that
   [image]
4. Your address bar will now contain a permalink to the code you just ran, you will get the same address if you copy the address of the "URL" hyperlink that appears in place of the "Share This Code" button

Answer (score 6):

Jonathan Mee gave a good answer to your question for one meaning of the word "link", but I think you might have meant another. I interpret your question as, "How do I create multiple .cc files on Wandbox, and get Wandbox to link them together?" i.e. "link" as in *pass to the linker*, not as in *get a URL for*.

See my example here: https://wandbox.org/permlink/LJBCKZlzEYndAWdV

- To create more than just the main code file, click the big bold "+" sign directly above line 1 of your code, just outside the text box. This will create a new tab named "noname-1". That tab represents a new code file.
- To give that code file a real name, click on "noname-1" to switch to that tab, and then click on "noname-1" again. The name will become editable. Change it to "beta.cc".
- However, when you click "Run", Wandbox will compile *only the code in your main file!* Your extra file "beta.cc" just sits there and doesn't get linked in. This is because Wandbox doesn't know the purpose of this new file — is it code? is it a header file that you just want to `#include`? is it a data file needed by your program at runtime? So Wandbox will only ever implicitly compile and link the code in the *main tab*.
- To get Wandbox to compile and link "beta.cc" alongside the main file, just do the same thing you'd do on your own machine: Add "beta.cc" to the compiler command line! The text input box for "Compiler Options:" is in the left sidebar. Each *line* of options turns into a single argument to the compiler, i.e. if you're trying to add two extra code files you should say

  ```
  beta.cc
  gamma.cc
  -O3
  ```

  and not

  ```
  beta.cc gamma.cc -O3
  ```
- As usual, once you've clicked "Run", you can click "Share" to get a permalink.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but yeah, the OP and I kinda share a brain, making it hard for me to misinterpret the intention of the question. Nonetheless, I can see how your answer may also be relevant to people who may visit, thus I've given you a +1.